# How do I programatically set the SharePoint's site collections Search Center property?

Tags: sharepoint, search, properties, sitecollection

I have a site collection and I want to set the search center value to be the same as another site collection. The site collection is created in code, so I need to be able to set the property after the site collection has been created.

How can I do this programatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This setting is stored in the property bag of the SPWeb object. You can update it as follows:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server/site"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
  web.AllProperties["SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL"] = "/searchcenter/pages";
  web.Update();
}
```